# Unable to render footer using Asciidoctor pdf

Tags: asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I'm trying to render a document with asciidoctor-pdf which has a footer with chapter title/page number. From the examples found so far I have come with this:

```
= Title of the book
:notitle:
:toc: left
:toclevels: 8 
:sectnums:
:sectnumlevels: 8
:source-highlighter: coderay 
:icons: font
:front-cover-image: pic.jpg

footer:
  height: 0.5in
  line_height: 1
  recto_content:
    right: '{chapter-title} | *{page-number}*'
  verso_content:
    left: '*{page-number}* | {chapter-title}

   == Chapter 1
```

However it does not produce the footer. I've tried both using the footer and the :footer top directive.
Any help what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to style your pdfs you can not put your settings in the adoc-file. You have to use pdf-theming. You find a long explanation [here](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/master/docs/theming-guide.adoc)

A very short summary looks like

1. create a file `basic-theme.yml` in directory `themes` ([example for basic-theme.yml](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/master/docs/theming-guide.adoc))
2. put your footer settings `basic-theme.yml`
3. use your styles `asciidoctor-pdf -a pdf-stylesdir=themes -a pdf-style=basic` [Details](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/master/docs/theming-guide.adoc#applying-your-theme)